# error on form submit if no second parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i submit my form and if the second parameter is empty.

**It throws error.**

> Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
>   Filename: user/Users_groups.php Line Number: 250

I know there is no second parameter. $this->session->userdata('modify')

```
if (!in_array('user/users_groups', $this->session->userdata('modify'))) {
$this->error['warning'] = 'You do not have permission to modify';
}
```

Is there away to make it stop throwing that error when user or I try to submit form if no second parameter `$this->session->userdata('modify')`

But still have that code.

Comment: place an @ before in_array `@in_array(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check first if parameters are valid:

```
<?php

    if(is_array($this->session->userdata('modify')) && !empty($this->session->userdata('modify')))
    {
        if (!in_array('user/users_groups', $this->session->userdata('modify')))
        {
            $this->error['warning'] = 'You do not have permission to modify';
        }
    }else{/* handle errors */}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the null value with an empty array before the if statement:

Could use a ternary operator like this:

```
$array = (is_array($this->session->userdata('modify'))) 
    ? $this->session->userdata('modify') 
    : Array()
```

It will use the 'modify' array if it's an array, else will pass an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I would also check array_search() function because it can be compared with NULL wich is returned if irregular parameters set.

> [5.3.0    As with all internal PHP functions as of 5.3.0, array_search() returns NULL if invalid parameters are passed to it.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)